# C# Abstract class clarification

Tags: c#

As abstract class can not be initialized,why the constructors are allowed?

I thought ,Incase i need to pass information to base class (abstract class in this class),i need to have constructor. I .. mean

```
     abstract class Person    
     {
        string regNo,name;

        public Person(string regNo,string name)
        {
            this.regNo = regNo;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public string RegNo
        {
            get { return regNo; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
        }

    }

    class student : Person
    {
        student(string regno, string name)
            : base(regno, name)
        {
        }
    }
```

is this the purpose the constructor is allowed inside abstract class?

Comment: if no member of the base class is abstract, then what's the point of letting Person to be abstract?

Answer (score 18):

Although it cannot be instantiated *on its own*, an abstract class can have constructors that would be called by the constructors of its derived classes.

This is particularly useful for the initialization of the members included in the base itself. (i.e. when the derived class' constructor includes a reference to "base()" ).

And indeed as Jason Down reminds us, a class always has a parameter-less default constructor provided, if such a constructor isn't explicitly defined.

Comment: Don't forget too, that even an abstract class will have a no argument constructor generated for it automatically if you do not create one yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Udanamehar,
   The primary reason that I use abstract is that I've identified that entity as something that I'll reuse quite a bit.  So, I might write some code like:

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public int StudentID { get; protected set; }

    public Student(int studentID, string regNo,string name) : base(regNo,Name)
    {
        this.StudentID = studentID;
    }

}
```

I'd verbalize it something like "... All students are Persons" therefore we have an 'is a' relationship to that is clearly expressed.  I didn't actually compile and test the example above . . but you get the idea.

Hope this helps . . .

Answer (score 1):

In a simplistic sense,
programmers being lazy, and laziness being the virtue of creativity and efficiency,
I would like all the constructor activities common to all derived classes of a base/super class to be commonly placed in the base/super class.

In the following illustration, all employees are provided healthcare and salary but not all employees have the same dimensions of expertise.

```
abstract class Employee{
  public Employee(){
    setHealthCare();
    setSalary();}

  ....}

class Programmer:Employee{
  public Programmer(){
    setLanguages();}
  ....}

class BeanCounter:Employee{
  public BeanCounter(){
    setBeans();}
  ....}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a constructor in an abstract class to implement logic that is specific to it. For example, you would initialize private fields in that constructor especially if they are aren't default values, because the derived class can't see the private fields anymore.

A constructor with one or more arguments in an abstract class also might initialize the behavior of the abstract class in some certain way that is important. Mostly you will find that it is recommended to wrap those constructor overloads in your derived class.

What's indeed a little bit irritating or even a design flaw in C# (or the whole .NET CLI possibly) is that you can define a **public** constructor in an abstract class, as it is always effectively **protected** then in that case. I for one always declare my abstract class constructors **protected** (or less visible if necessary of course).